# jQuery insertAfter do not increased parent().length

Tags: jquery

I have a div container with other divs inside.

`divContainer.children().length` is not always correct.

If I use `SomeNewDiv.insertAfter(SomeDivInTheDivContainer)`
The `divContainer.children().length` is NOT increased with 1

If I use `divContainer.append(SomeNewDiv)`
The `divContainer.children().length` is increased with 1

I have tried using first `divContainer.append(SomeNewDiv)` and then moved it with `SomeNewDiv.insertAfter(SomeDivInTheDivContainer)`
But then the `divContainer.children().length` is NOT increased with 1

I can see, that the `SomeNewDiv` is placed correct in the `divContainer`, but the length is not correct.

I can’t see why?

Comment: Need more than pseudo code for us to help... Need the HTML and the real code.

Comment: We can't see why either without a [mcve].

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/skbbuaLe/1/ to begin with.

Comment: Works like a charm https://jsfiddle.net/798Lon3f/1/

Comment: Working fine https://jsfiddle.net/dosehvyg/